# "MySQL INSERT INTO ... SELECT" bug in decimal values

Tags: mysql, type-conversion

Here's my query:

```
INSERT INTO `temp_map_196`
(SELECT DISTINCT
   NULL,NULL,NULL,
   t1.`price`,
   t1.`price`,
   COUNT(*) AS `count`
 FROM  `raw_table_1` t1
 GROUP BY `price`
 ORDER BY `count` DESC)
```

`t1.price` is a `DECIMAL` column. The values are being inserted into a `varchar` column.

`1, 10, 10.5` all get inserted correctly.

But `1.6` and `1.8` become `1.60000002384186` and `1.79999995231628`

If I change the query to this:

```
INSERT INTO `temp_map_196`
(SELECT
   NULL,NULL,NULL,
   1.6,
   1.6,
   1
)
```

Everything works fine.

Everything also works when I change the original query to:

```
INSERT INTO `temp_map_196`
(SELECT DISTINCT
NULL,NULL,NULL,
CAST (t1.`price` AS DECIMAL(8,2)),
CAST (t1.`price` AS DECIMAL(8,2)),
COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM  `raw_table_1` t1
GROUP BY `price`
ORDER BY `count` DESC)
```

But I can't do that because the column will not always receive decimal values.

Why is MySQL inserting these weird decimals when it does not appear to be in the source data? (Taking the `SELECT` part of the `INSERT` query and running it by itself, there are no such weird values).

Comment: `But I can't do that because the column will not always receive decimal values.` - Why are you not always receiving decimal values? That can't be since `price` is decimal.

Comment: Why are you ordering a query that's used to populate anither table? That seems a bit of a wate.

Comment: try `CAST(t1.price AS CHAR)`

Comment: what is the issue if you price comes as 12.00 in the case where you dont have decimals?

Comment: this maybe will help you .

   [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191365/store-in-char-column-getting-from-decimal-column-in-db2)

Comment: @juergend because the table is a temporary table created to handle different kinds of data operations. Some are mathetmatical, some string based. Price is not the only source data that would be handled. Color could also be handled there.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers stored in a `DECIMAL` column are handled internally as strings. This way, there's no data loss due to conversion from/to binary base.

However, sometimes MySQL *forgets* that a value comes from a `DECIMAL` column and the values get automatically cast to `FLOAT`, which is a pure numeric column type which is subject to precision loss. It's fairly rare and I'm not fully sure of the reason but it tends to happen when values come from a subquery.

In your case, since the final destination of the number is a string, I suggest that you cast to **string** as soon as possible:

```
INSERT INTO `temp_map_196`
(SELECT DISTINCT
NULL,NULL,NULL,
CAST (t1.`price` AS CHAR),
CAST (t1.`price` AS CHAR),
COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM  `raw_table_1` t1
GROUP BY `price`
ORDER BY `count` DESC)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO your_insert_table (SELECT your_select_table REPLACE(t1.`price`, ',', '.'))
```

Comment: It is best to add a description of what the sql code is doing to help them understand why your answer works.

Comment: I don't think changing comma to dot would help.